# Programatically generate gridview with specific template

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am currently trying to generate a `Gridview` that will look something like this.

[image: Example]

The first two columns are done with `Boundfield`, where I will grab based on the data given in database.

However, the problem comes in when I've to have the row of `AM` & `PM`.

Is there a way to do a `colspan` for the header of the date and create a row just for the `AM` & `PM`? Because `AM` & `PM` is not counted as columns, instead the `10/11/2016` is a column.

ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAttendance" runat="server">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="traineeID" HeaderText="Trainee ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="idNum" HeaderText="ID" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, take a look at my snippet and adjust it to your needs. The snippet will apply the `ColSpan` in the default header and will add an extra header row to the GridView.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        int spanColumn_1_start = 2;
        int spanColumn_1_length = 2;

        //apply colspan
        e.Row.Cells[spanColumn_1_start].ColumnSpan = spanColumn_1_length;

        //remove the spanned cells
        for (int i = 1; i < spanColumn_1_length; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(spanColumn_1_start + 1);
        }

        //note that the startindex of the 2nd colspan is set after removing cells for 1st colspan
        int spanColumn_2_start = 3;
        int spanColumn_2_length = 2;

        //apply colspan
        e.Row.Cells[spanColumn_2_start].ColumnSpan = spanColumn_2_length;

        //remove the spanned cells
        for (int i = 1; i < spanColumn_2_length; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(spanColumn_2_start + 1);
        }
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //to add a row above the normal gridview header, use: if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.DataItemIndex == 0)
    {
        //cast the sender as gridview
        GridView gridView = sender as GridView;

        //create a new gridviewrow
        GridViewRow gridViewRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

        //add some cells
        TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();
        tableCell.Text = "";
        tableCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
        gridViewRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

        tableCell = new TableCell();
        tableCell.Text = "AM";
        gridViewRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

        tableCell = new TableCell();
        tableCell.Text = "PM";
        gridViewRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

        tableCell = new TableCell();
        tableCell.Text = "AM";
        gridViewRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

        tableCell = new TableCell();
        tableCell.Text = "PM";
        gridViewRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);

        //add the new row to the gridview
        gridView.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(1, gridViewRow);
    }
}
```

The result will look like this

[image]

Comment: For the `RowCreated`, so if I have another addition of 3 dates? Then is it possible to dynamically add `AM` `PM`?

Comment: Anyway, just want to say thank you for the efforts, I'm trying out the codes currently. Cheers. (:

Comment: Yes, just add 6 more `TableCell` Controls to the row.