# Split a GridView Column into two columns as my attached image shows in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to split every cell into two column and put some value in those divided cells. I created my Headers like below

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {


                e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "";
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Monday <br> morning | afternoon";
                e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "Tuesday <br> morning | afternoon";
                e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "Wednsday <br> morning | afternoon";
                e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Thursday <br> morning | afternoon";
                e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "Friday  <br> morning | afternoon";
                e.Row.Cells[6].Text = "Saturday <br> morning | afternoon";
                e.Row.Cells[7].Text = "Sunday  <br> morning | afternoon";
}
```

But I want them as image nr 2 shows. How do I do to achive that? Thank you in advance.[image]

**Update**: This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

[image]

Update: 
The user input startDate and endDate and inserts to "tplHoliday" the I use

```
private List<DateTime> GetDatesBetween(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            List<DateTime> allDates = new List<DateTime>();
            for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
                allDates.Add(date);
            return allDates;

        }
```

and make insertion every date to tplDates. I feel like this insertion is un necesserily but it gives me easy selection to my gridView with following code

```
 SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand((@"select e.FirstName,
                        count(case when d.Dates = @day1 THEN 1 END),
                        count(case when d.Dates = @day2 THEN 1 END),
                        count(case when d.Dates = @day3 THEN 1 END),
                        count(case when d.Dates = @day4 THEN 1 END),
                        count(case when d.Dates = @day5 THEN 1 END),
                        count(case when d.Dates = @day6 THEN 1 END),
                        count(case when d.Dates = @day7 THEN 1 END)
                        from tplEmployee e

                        left join tplDates d
                        on e.EmployeeId = d.EmployeeId
                        group by e.FirstName"), connection);

                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day1", (DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).ToShortDateString()));
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day2", (DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()));
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day3", (DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(2).ToShortDateString()));
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day4", (DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(3).ToShortDateString()));
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day5", (DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(4).ToShortDateString()));
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day6", (DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(5).ToShortDateString()));
                cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day7", (DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(6).ToShortDateString()));




                    connection.Open();

                    GridView1.DataSource = cmd5.ExecuteReader();
                    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Tha's why you see 1 .. and 0  but I don't know how to handle this problematics. I realy want to see as last updated image. I'am trying and trying and fighting with different codes but I'an achive my goal. My dream is to achive as last updated GridView image... please tell how how to do..

Comment: Take a look at my answer here. It shows how you can add an extra header row and/or apply colspan. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530769/programatically-generate-gridview-with-specific-template/40534847#40534847

Comment: @VDWWD Thank you for your response, I'am so new in this GridView staffs.. I tried your code but for the first I lose the hole wednsday.. I changed many numbers in your code but stil I can't get as I want. Please help me if you have time... Thank you again

Comment: I've added an answer.

Comment: then you will wanna color the lines differently. these are all different questions man.

Comment: whats your data structure? I meant the model?

Comment: @naveen No color. I just want to be clear what I want to do. Thank you for your response

Comment: I understand that you need 15 columns and the same logic @VDWWD suggested

Comment: @naveen thank you sir, Now I have updated with the hole idea...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple snippet that adds a header row to the GridView with the week names.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        //cast the sender as gridview
        GridView gridView = sender as GridView;

        //create a new gridviewrow
        GridViewRow gridViewRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);

        //add an empty cell
        TableCell tableCellEmpty = new TableCell();
        tableCellEmpty.Text = "";
        gridViewRow.Cells.Add(tableCellEmpty);

        //create a date that is a monday
        DateTime week = new DateTime(2016, 11, 14);

        //add 7 weekday cells
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();
            tableCell.Text = week.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd");
            tableCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            gridViewRow.Cells.Add(tableCell);
        }

        //add the new row to the gridview
        gridView.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, gridViewRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you VDWWD. Now I can se all my weekdays but those sub Headers  (AM and PM) are making me crazy.. ;)  I changed int spanColumn_1_start = 2; to  int spanColumn_1_start = 1; becouse I'am starting subheading from monday ...  but then they don't much with my days... I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Why span those? If your dataset has 15 columns (7x am/pm plus name column) then you don't need to span anything. I based the above snippet on a grid with 15 columns.

Comment: If you have 7 weekday columns, remove `tableCell.ColumnSpan = 2;` from my snippet.

Comment: waw.. almost near to solution (uppdated image).. ;) but how can I split now the headers... what to write code in GridView_RowDataBound() ?

Comment: If you need to split every item in the dataset, I think you should rethink your way of storing data. I get that you use a boolean for AM/PM. But it would be better to use a boolean for AM and one for PM. That way the grid works and you won't run into trouble when someone needs to be in both AM and PM. Like with Anna in the second image.

Comment: @VDWWD Now you have my hole problem.. ;) I mean my hole idé what I want to achive... please help me to solv this problem the best way. As I said I'am new for asp and GridView. I want to look like the last GridView image (black and white GridView)

Comment: The problem now is getting the date from the DB in a correct way. Unfortunately this is not my area of expertise. Ask a new question on how to get that table data from sql in a weekly view.